Twilio Studio - Time of day routing split in call flow
Does any one have any experience, or could share an example of the best way to build in a day of day split to a callflow that would allow for a recorded message to play first if a call comes in during the same time of day (between 11am - 2pm CDT Mon-Fri) before then connecting up the the rest of the call flow?
Mostly looking for any help guides

I recommend using a function to perform the validation, where it returns true or false if it is within the allowed time.
Here is an example:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/quickstart/time-of-day-routing
